# CAN Bus Inter Frame Spacing (IFS) -- Three Bits or Seven?

Tags: can

If you google around for the length of the CAN Bus Inter Frame Spacing (IFS), you can find some references that say it's 3 bits and others that say it's 7 bits.

[Google Link for 3-bit search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%223-bit%22%20spacing%20can%20bus)

[Google Link for 7-bit search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%227-bit%22%20spacing%20can%20bus)

Why is there this discrepancy?  Did the minimum IFS get changed to 3 bits at at some point in the history of CAN Bus?

Comment: When in doubt, refer to the specification.  You'd need to buy the [current specification](https://www.iso.org/standard/63648.html) from ISO for an amount that is (in my opinion) unreasonable for a hobbyiest but quite reasonable if you're working for a company -- it's the same cost as a screw-up that adds an hour or two to your day in the US.  Either talk your boss into that, or if you're working on an older version of CAN try to find Bosch's original specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The early [CAN 2.0 specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20221010170747/http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/webres/can20.pdf), published in 1991, already specified an IFS field length of 3 bits.

An excerpt from chapter 3.2.5 on page 53:

> 3.2.5 INTERFRAME SPACING
>
> DATA FRAMEs and REMOTE FRAMEs are separated from preceding frames whatever type they are [..] by a bit field called INTERFRAME SPACE. [..]
>
> INTERFRAME SPACE
> contains the bit fields INTERMISSION and BUS IDLE [..].
>
> [image]
>
> [..]
>
> INTERMISSION
> consists of three 'recessive' bits.
>
> [..]
>
> BUS IDLE
> The period of BUS IDLE may be of arbitrary length.

I believe sources specifying a 7-bit IFS simply contain a typo or copy/paste error (which could be plausible, since the preceding EOF field is 7 bits in length).

Answer (score 2):

Some sources might be confusing the End of frame field (7 bits) with the Inter frame spacing (3 bits). Both of these for a total of 7+3 bits come at the end of each CAN frame and they are recessive. I think the only reason they separated them is because the IFS isn't really considered as part of the frame, but rather the minimum delay between two frames.

As for the rationale for the end of frame field, it allows an active error frame (6 dominant) in case of form error, missing ACK, wrong CRC etc to get transmitted without affecting the real-time behavior of other nodes.